# Formulario de dos columnas en Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap

Buenos días a todos,

estoy haciendo un formulario web en ASP con Bootstrap en dos columnas y para la versión móvil no me mantiene el ancho de los labels y queda un poco raro (no doy muchos detalles porque creo que viéndolo será más visual)

Escritorio:

[image: Escritorio]

Móvil:

[image: Móvil]

Código:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="MainContent_text_reg_nombre" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Empresa*:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$text_reg_nombre" id="MainContent_text_reg_nombre" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="MainContent_text_reg_telefono" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Teléfono:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$text_reg_telefono" id="MainContent_text_reg_telefono" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="MainContent_text_reg_email" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$text_reg_email" id="MainContent_text_reg_email" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="MainContent_text_reg_web" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Web:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$text_reg_web" id="MainContent_text_reg_web" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="MainContent_text_reg_direccion" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Dirección:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$text_reg_direccion" id="MainContent_text_reg_direccion" class="form-control" onkeyup="sync()" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="MainContent_text_reg_localidad" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Localidad:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$text_reg_localidad" id="MainContent_text_reg_localidad" class="form-control" onkeyup="sync()" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="MainContent_text_reg_provincia" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Provincia:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$text_reg_provincia" id="MainContent_text_reg_provincia" class="form-control" onkeyup="sync()" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="MainContent_text_reg_cp" class="col-sm-4 control-label">CP:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$text_reg_cp" id="MainContent_text_reg_cp" class="form-control" onkeyup="sync()" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Intente agregar un comentario pero no pude poner imagen así que no me quedo de otra que pooner como respuesta, y si bien no es una respuesta, espero te sirva. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debería ser un problema de algo que estés configurando en tu css, ya que tu codigo aparentemente está bien, y es mas lo pruebo y se adapta bien el responsive
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por lo tanto puedes verificar que no tengas ningun align o algo en tu css que esté afectando la clase del boostrapp

Comment: Tienes más razón que un santo... Estuve haciendo pruebas y había dejado un
"display: flex;
justify-content: center;"
donde no tocaba. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Amigo la estructura del codigo debe ser esta

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone" class="col-md-3 control-label">
                    <strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone" aria-hidden="true"></span></strong>
                </label>
                <input id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Teléfono" value="">
        </div>
```

si agregas un div col va a descuadrarte el formulario

debes quitar este div

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
```

O en caso de que no te funcione puedes usar

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>[label del campo]</dt>
        <dd>[Tu Campo]</dd>
</dl>
```

que es otra estructura de bootstrap muy usada para alinear contenidos.